# Converting python float to bytes

Tags: python, numpy, binary-data

I want to convert a Python float into a byte array, encoding it as a 32 bit little-endian IEEE floating point number, in order to write it to a binary file.

What is the modern Pythonic way to do that in Python 3? For ints I can do `my_int.to_bytes(4,'little')`, but there is no `to_bytes` method for floats.

It's even better if I can do this in one shot for every float in a numpy array (with dtype numpy.float32). But note that I need to get it as a byte array, not just write the array to a file immediately.

There are some similar-sounding questions, but they seem mostly to be about getting the hex digits, not writing to a binary file.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/struct.html

Comment: The right tools for manipulating individual, native Python scalars are usually not the right tools for manipulating NumPy arrays. If you want a NumPy solution, I recommend specifically asking about NumPy and leaving regular Python types out (and expect to get non-NumPy answers anyway from people who don't know NumPy).

Comment: @user2357112 I'd be happy with a non-numpy answer, since I'm writing the floats one at a time. I mentioned numpy mostly because a numpy solution won't hurt (I'm importing it anyway) and might be useful to know in the future.

Comment: You might want to try to find a way to avoid writing them one at a time. That'll be slow.

Comment: @user2357112 you're right. Luckily, the numpy solutions have enabled me to do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the right `dtype` you can write the array's data buffer to a bytestring or to a binary file:

```
In [449]: x = np.arange(4., dtype='<f4')                                        
In [450]: x                                                                     
Out[450]: array([0., 1., 2., 3.], dtype=float32)
In [451]: txt = x.tostring()                                                    
In [452]: txt                                                                   
Out[452]: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00@@'
In [453]: x.tofile('test')                                                                                                                           
In [455]: np.fromfile('test','<f4')                                             
Out[455]: array([0., 1., 2., 3.], dtype=float32)
In [459]: with open('test','br') as f: print(f.read())                          
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00@@'
```

Change endedness:

```
In [460]: x.astype('>f4').tostring()                                            
Out[460]: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00?\x80\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00@@\x00\x00'
```

Comment: How can I specify the endian-ness?

Comment: '<f4' versus '>f4'

Comment: Great, thanks, this works very well. For future reference, `tostring` is a compatibility alias for `tobytes`.

Answer (score 5):

NumPy arrays come with a [`tobytes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tobytes.html) method that gives you a dump of their raw data bytes:

```
arr.tobytes()
```

You can specify an `order` argument to use either C-order (row major) or F-order (column major) for multidimensional arrays.

Since you want to dump the bytes to a file, you may also be interested in the [`tofile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html) method, which dumps the bytes to a file directly:

```
arr.tofile(your_file)
```

`tofile` always uses C-order.

If you need to change endianness, you can use the [`byteswap`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.byteswap.html) method. (`newbyteorder` has a more convenient signature, but doesn't change the underlying bytes, so it won't affect `tobytes`.)

```
import sys
if sys.byteorder=='big':
    arr = arr.byteswap()
data_bytes = arr.tobytes()
```

Comment: How can I specify the endian-ness?

Comment: @Nathaniel: Answer expanded.

Comment: Thanks! From hpaulj's answer it seems I can also specify endianness in the dtype, as another way to do it

Comment: How do you go backto thenumpy array from this dump?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `struct` to `pack` the `bytes` like,

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('<f', 3.14) # little-endian
b'\xc3\xf5H@'
>>> struct.pack('>f', 3.14) # big-endian
b'@H\xf5\xc3'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are `save/savez` methods in `numpy`:

Store data to disk, and load it again:

```
>>> np.save('/tmp/123', np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]))
>>> np.load('/tmp/123.npy')
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Store compressed data to disk, and load it again:

```
>>> a=np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
>>> b=np.array([1, 2])
>>> np.savez('/tmp/123.npz', a=a, b=b)
>>> data = np.load('/tmp/123.npz')
>>> data['a']
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
>>> data['b']
array([1, 2])
>>> data.close()
```

Comment: `save` differs from `tofile` in that it also saves the `shape` and `dtype` in an initial data block.

Comment: @hpaulj `shape` and `dtype` don't take much space, but play the crucial role in flawless reading and converting the data back instead of getting a bunch of binary garbage.

Comment: As a complete file format, `.npy` is definitely more informative and useful than just a raw byte dump. As an intermediate representation or a component of a larger file, a raw byte dump may be significantly more useful.