# converting float (32 bit) and double (64 bit) to bytes

Tags: python, floating-point, byte

I am trying to send a data buffer from Python over TCP to a C++ server.

The TCP pack order is defined as follows:

1. bytes[0 till 3] must be an integer (32 bit) with value = length of the buffer
2. bytes[4 till 7] must be a float (32 bit)
3. bytes[8 till 15] must be a double (64 bit)

I have successfully implemented the first point (length of the buffer) in the following way.

```
buffer = bytearray(bufferLength)  # bufferLength is an integer
buffer[0] = bufferLength.to_bytes(4, 'little')[0]
buffer[1] = bufferLength.to_bytes(4, 'little')[1]
buffer[2] = bufferLength.to_bytes(4, 'little')[2]
buffer[3] = bufferLength.to_bytes(4, 'little')[3]
```

which works perfectly.
But how to convert the two floats (32 bit and 64 bit)?

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel - https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is what I'm looking for =)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting python float to bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58813707/converting-python-float-to-bytes)